Asynchronous I/O: Any way to get a report on how many bytes code "thinks" it wrote in an I/O request?
I am trying to write files with a C code using asynchronous I/O (librt and aio.h).  The current use case is several threads writing several files simultaneously, but this could change to several threads writing parts of a single file.  Diagnostic statements indicate that the AIO is being directed to write the correct number of bytes.  Further statements indicate that the files are written, and then synced and closed, as required.  However, after all this, many of the files are of zero length.  This should not be the case.  I am trying to diagnose this problem.
So, as I said, the number of bytes being asked of the async I/O is correct.  So, if I can, I want to go a step deeper and find a way to get async I/O to report the number of bytes it at least "thinks" it wrote after the I/O request completes.  Note that looking directly at the files that are opened but never populated won't help.  I already know they will be zero, and shouldn't be.  So something like fstat is a non-starter.  I expected that since a simple printf returns the number of characters it writes, surely async I/O would have a way get the number of output bytes, but I haven't been able to find anything.  Is there a way to do this?

Isn't the value returned by read() and write() functions the same as what they 'thought' they read and wrote?  Also, are you always sure to set the file pointer to the end of the file before writing? This has bitten me a couple of times.

"surely async I/O would have a way get the number of output bytes" - Why surely?  Given that a successful aio_write function call implies how many bytes it wrote, there is no need for the I/O system to keep a running count of bytes read or written for each file descriptor.  Application code can do that for itself ... in the small subset of cases where that information is needed.

aio_write will either write the requested bytes, or will return an error if it can't. So if it didn't report an error, it wrote aiocbp->aio_nbytes bytes.

Hmmm…a call to POSIX aio_write()
either returns 0 or -1, indicating whether the call was queued successfully or not.  When the call completes, the information will be available in the AIO control block

@Jonathan Leffler, Yes, the error is checked using aio_error. The OP didn't ask how to use aio_write.
